# Find the characteristic equation for a recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a recurrence relation like Fibonacci or Lucas, we have
$$F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} \quad \begin{Bmatrix}F(0)=0\\F(1)=1 \end{Bmatrix}$$
$$L_{n}=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2} \quad \begin{Bmatrix}L(0)=2\\L(1)=1 \end{Bmatrix}$$
What is the characteristic polynomial for each of these sequences, and **How to find** it.
Wikipedia has a definition for these particular examples here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving
The sequence is defined generically as $$a_n = c_1 a_{n-1}+c_2 a_{n-2}.$$ Then, the characteristic polynomial is given as $$p(t)=t^d -c_1t^{d-1}-c_2t^{d-2} \tag{eq 1}$$ where $d$ is the number of coefficients. $$p(t)=t^2-c_1t-c_2$$ and for these two cases, $c_1=1$ and $c_2=1$ so $$p(t): t^2-t-1=0$$ is the characteristic equation for both of them.
I am rather sure that the same polynomial is correct for both sequences since, I was able to use it and derive a closed form equation which correctly gets F(n) or L(n). To do that, I followed this link https://math.ucr.edu/~res/math153/history07a.pdf
While it is nice to know a definition as in eq(1), I am used to having, in this case, a 2x2 matrix to obtain the characteristic polynomial as $(\lambda I-A)\boldsymbol{v}=0$.  But I just can't see what matrix to use here such that both Lucas and Fibonacci resolve to the same polynomial.

Comment: Similar to constant coefficient differential equations, try a solution $a_n=r^n$. Solve the resulting algebraic equation for all values of $r$. The general solution is a linear combination of these: $c_1r_1^n +c_2r_2^n + \cdots $ with coefficients $c$ determined by the initial conditions (known $a_0$ and $a_1$ in your examples)

Comment: @Sal Boyce and DiPrima to the rescue.  It's been about 50 years since I looked at general solutions for multiple constant coeff diff eqs.  It came back fast.  Twas a success. Thanks.

Comment: Great, no problem!